# Azure policy for network subnet

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

How can I set up a standard naming convention for Azure Network subnet... I have the policy, however it doesn't seem to work

```js
{
  "if": {
    "allOf": [{
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets"
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "field": "name",
          "match": "nncc-???-subnet"
        }
      },
      {
        "not": {
          "field": "name",
          "match": "nncc-????-subnet"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "Deny"
  }
}
```

Any tips here

Comment: did you assign it? thats the only thing i can think of. this looks valid

Comment: Yes I did assign it

Comment: Is this really an Azure API Management related question?

Comment: @KaiWalter I do not understand your comments..

Answer (score 0):

Sharing below information for broader audience -

We have noticed that this question is a duplicate of this -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f39a0c36-3e36-4a7d-bd2c-a428c074329a/naming-convention-for-network-subnet?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork MSDN forum question.